# converging diverging nozzle de laval nozzle

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]

Hi all,
is it possible in real situation or this calculation example is only "Assuming"
conditions?
More specific : to build such nozzle with mentioned :exit: velocity

Many thanks and Best regards!

Comment: What is the question?  "Is it possible to build such a nozzle in real situation?"   Why these doubts? If the calculation ok,  where is the problem with the construction?

Comment: thanks a lot . just for confirmation. More specific : is it possible to build such nozzle to operate under these conditions.